# ML inequality: show that $\left|\int_{\gamma} {\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16}} \mathrm{d}z\right| \le \frac{3\sqrt 10}{7}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $D$ be the disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z+1|<3\}$.
>   Show that 
>   $$\left|\int_{\gamma} {\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16}} \mathrm{d}z\right| \le \frac{3\sqrt 10}{7}$$
>   *for all paths* $\gamma$ in $D$ with initial point $-3$ and final point $i$.

I started with the Estimation lemma (ML inequality), and chose a straight line to be the path of minimum length between $-3$ and $i$. Therefore, I got $L=\sqrt 10$ as the minimum path length. I also noticed that the ingrand, $f(z)=\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16}$, is analytic within the disk $D$.

**Question**: How do I show calculate the maximum value of the integrand *along any path* between $-3$ and $i$? Also, is using the ML inequality the best approach?

Comment: Choosing a path is equivalent to choosing any other path $\gamma_1$, since $f$ is analytic so $\int_{\gamma_1\cup\gamma}f=0$ which $\gamma$ is your path.

Comment: @Nosrati: Thanks. So if I understand, you are saying that I can choose the straight line path from $-3$ to $i$ and find the maximum value of $f(z)$ along this path. I will give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out and will answer my own question, per @Nosrati suggestion:

Choosing $\gamma$ to be the straight line between $-3$ and $i$, a parametrization for $\gamma$ is $z(t)=3(t-1)+it$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.
As such, the length of the line between $-3$ and $i$ is $L=\sqrt 10$.

Now,
$$f(z)=\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16} \rightarrow |f(z)|=\left|\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16}\right|\le \frac{3}{|z^2+16|}$$
since $|ze^z|=|z| e^{\text{Re} (z)}$ and $e^{\text{Re(z)}} \le 1$, along with $|z| \le 3$ along $\gamma$.

Using the triangle inequality $|z + w| \ge ||z|-|w||$,
$$\frac{3}{|z^2+16|} \le \frac{3}{||z^2|-16|}=\frac{3}{||z|^2-16|}$$

Using $z=3(t-1)+it \rightarrow |z|^2=9(t-1)^2 + t^2$, $$ ||z|^2 - 16|=|10t^2-18t-7|$$

On the interval $0 \le t \le 1$, the minimum value of $|10t^2-18t-7|$, which will maximize $f(z)$, is $7$.

Therefore, $|f(z)| \le M = \frac{3}{7}$.

Hence, $$\left|\int_{\gamma} {\frac{ze^z}{z^2+16}} \mathrm{d}z\right| \le ML=\frac{3}{7}\sqrt 10$$